# Использование клавиатуры в Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

у меня есть код, по нажатию на кнопку в программе он выводит звук, а как сделать так, что бы по кнопке он выводил такой же звук? Проще говоря, чтоб нажатие клавиши = нажатию кнопки в программе.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Demo, self).__init__()

        self.url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('D:\\Downloads\\filename.mp3')
        self.content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(self.url)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
        self.play_btn = QPushButton('Play Sound', self)
        self.play_btn.clicked.connect(self.player.play)       


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [setShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#shortcut-prop), пример:

```
self.play_btn.setShortcut('Ctrl+Shift+T')
```

---

В [setShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#shortcut-prop) кроме строки можно передавать объект [QKeySequence](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html) и один из вариантов создания [QKeySequence](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html) предусматривает передачу перечисления, описывающего действие, типа `QKeySequence.Find`