# Звук по кнопке и по клавише

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, key

У меня реализован звук по нажати кнопки в программе, а как сделать так, чтобы я например нажимал `1 на клавиатуре`, и выходил такой же звук, если бы я нажал на первую кнопку. Так же со второй кнопкой.

Вот код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication


class Guitar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(250, 55, 1200, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Клавиши')

        self.first_button = QPushButton('Первая клавиша(клавиша 1)', self)
        self.first_button.resize(170, 50)
        self.first_button.move(40, 100)
        self.first_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self._play('D:\\Downloads\\First_str.mp3'))  

        self.second_button = QPushButton('Вторая клавиша(клавиша 2)', self)
        self.second_button.resize(170, 50)
        self.second_button.move(40, 200)
        self.second_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self._play('D:\\Downloads\\Second_str.mp3')) 

    def _play(self, url):
        self.url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(url)
        self.content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(self.url)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(self.content)
        self.player.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Guitar()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: вам же уже давали ответ на этот вопрос!!! [ВОТ ТУТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205120/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо перегрузить метод `QWidget.keyPressEvent`, либо `QWidget.keyReleaseEvent`.

Например ([коды кнопок](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/core/Qt.Key.html)):

```
...
class Guelar(QWidget):

    ...

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_1:
            self._play('D:\\Downloads\\First_str.mp3')
        elif e.key() == Qt.Key_2:
            self._play('D:\\Downloads\\Second_str.mp3')
...
```